# Function to convert a decimal into that of any base

Tags: binary, hex, converters, higher-order-functions

I am doing this question via an Online learning platform, and there are test cases assigned which i must pass. **The topic is Higher Order Functions.**

Here is the question:

**Write a function make_decimal_to_n_ary_converter that accepts a number n where 1 < n < 17, and returns a number converter that converts a given decimal number into that of base n.**

**Below is my code**(I am supposed to use an inner function i.e converter(x))

```
    def make_decimal_to_n_ary_converter(n):
    def converter(x):
        if x==0 or x==1:   
            return x
        i=x
        b=('A','B','C','D','E','F')
        result = ""
        while i>0:
            a=i%n          #3
            if a<10:
                result = str(i%n)+result
            else:
                d=a-10
                result = b[d] + result
            i=i//n

        return result
    return converter

#Lines below are not to be changed, part of qn
decimal_to_binary = make_decimal_to_n_ary_converter(2)
decimal_to_octal = make_decimal_to_n_ary_converter(8)
decimal_to_hexadecimal = make_decimal_to_n_ary_converter(16)
```

**Here are some test cases that my code passes:**

decimal_to_binary(213)
11010101
decimal_to_octal(213)
325
decimal_to_hexadecimal(213)
D5
make_decimal_to_n_ary_converter(15)(213)
E3

However, my code fails some private test cases, and feedback that i received was that my logic in the while loop is wrong. However, after printing some numbers, i failed to see anything wrong. 
Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. My mistake was that for base cases x , i had to return a string instead.